# What is this tree growing in my dad's backyard?

Tags: identification, trees

This is in the Rio Grande Valley in Texas. There are a few of these with green and purple leaves up top that are about 4 feet tall at the moment. There are a few scattered around that are in different stages of growth. There is a mixture, some have this green purple others are all green. The leaves are fairly large (maybe 5 inches).Some leaves have 3 sections of leaves others have 5. I'm not sure how to describe them. The little seeds are about dime size and look like miniature bell peppers, without spikes or bumps, just the bell peppery groove, and are hard. They are all in an area of full sunlight. I really want to know what they are because they are very pretty and would like to take a few of the young ones to transplant.
[image: tree in texas]

[image: another view of a tree in texas]

[image: fruit of a tree in texas]